# Firebase isn't displaying CSS properly - specifically media query

Tags: css, firebase, web-hosting

I've decided to host my personal portfolio site on Firebase - mostly just for the quick and easy hosting and SSL.

Everything is working almost exactly as intended except that the media query for larger screens isn't being applied to the document.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){
```

The desktop screens are still getting the default mobile styles.
So as I'm writing this I noticed that it works fine from the default firebase URL https://haydos-personal-portfolio.web.app/
but from my own domain https://haydos.nz - the media query isn't working. Is it a caching issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing same issue try to do hard reload i.e <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>